# Can guided shell from a tank still lock on to aircrafts?

Tags: battlefield-3

Can the tanks guided shell still lock on to helicopters when someone puts up a soflam?
I thought it was possible before the big patch they once did but i havn't been able to find someone who wants to put up a soflamwhile i'm in the tank now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guided shell can normally lock onto ground vehicles though it can lock onto all targets when laser designated. Even to the ones without a direct line of sight.